# How to create google actions with one term name

Tags: actions-on-google

how can I name my google action with one name?
The following exception is occurring when trying to:

App names with only one word, or only one word that is not a prefix (such as "the" or "an"), are not normally allowed. If you need further guidance, please contact the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do exactly what it says - you contact support at the form at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/actions/support/.

In general, one-name actions won't be permitted unless you have the trademark or domain name with that same one word already. This name is a unique way to contact your Action, and for generic names or words, there would be far too many people trying to get the same one. In rare cases, it might be allowed (again - when you already have a clear claim on the word), but in general it is unlikely.